# Keyword not supported: '"data source'

Tags: c#, asp.net, runtime-error, connection-string

First off, I have looked at all the other SO questions related to this and nothing has helped.

Now, I just bought a asp.net hosting package and I am trying to get my site live. When I publish my site using webdeploy I specify the connectionstring they give me (I do not have it set in Web.config), with the box checked telling it to use this connectionstring at runtime.

However I get a `Keyword not supported: '"data source'.` error on every page I try to load.

Using this connectionstring:

```
"Data Source=tcp:ghql19384.discountasp.net;Initial
 Catalog=SQL2012_123456_name;User ID=SQL2012_123456_name_user;Password=******;"
```

I have tried writing the password aswell instead of copy pasting the one with the "***" But that does nothing.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try Server instead of Data Source. I find the following site useful when dealing with connection strings...http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: what sql software are you using on the back end?  SQL Server?  Oracle?  MySQL?